# Payment Gateway Authentication

Tags: apex, callout, namedcredentials, b2b-commerce, b2b

I am trying to setup [B2B Commerce Payments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.b2b_comm_lex_dev.meta/b2b_comm_lex_dev/b2b_comm_lex_checkout_payment_setup.htm) to use a Cyber Source Payment Gateway that I have already implemented but am having issues with the authentication.

The Cyber Source API that my Payment Gateway uses [handles authentication in a non trivial way](https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-gettingstarted/authentication/GenerateHeader/jwtTokenAuthentication.html). It requires me to set a Signature header which is a hashed checksum ([actually called a Message Authentication Code, or MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code)) using a combination of the payload, timestamp, domain, merchant Id, and API key.

I have this part ^ working *when* I call it outside of the context of B2B Payments. What I mean by this is that I can construct a payload, set the headers, and fire off a `HttpResponse response = http.send(request);` request and it works. But all the authentication is handled in Apex due to it's complexity. It does **not** use any of the authentication mechanisms built into a Named Credential.

I built the Payment Gateway using [forcedotcom/Core-Payments-Reference-Gateway-Integration-Adapters](https://github.com/forcedotcom/Core-Payments-Reference-Gateway-Integration-Adapters) as a guide. But it wasn't until I got around to trying to use it with B2B Commerce Payments that I noticed it doesn't send the request using `System.Http`, instead it uses [commercepayments.PaymentsHttp](https://github.com/forcedotcom/Core-Payments-Reference-Gateway-Integration-Adapters/blob/3351f56662a7ae65012eb10cf46baa5133d98065/PayeezyGatewayAdapter/classes/AbstractTransactionService.apex#L67) which seems to have some side effects.

- For example, since a Payment Gateway Adapter is linked to a Named Credential, the way you specify the request endpoint is slightly different. When setting the endpoint to be used with a `commercepayments.PaymentsHttp` you do **not** specify the base domain (not with a `callout:CyberSource` and not by hard coding it). Instead you only need to specify the relative path to be used after the domain listed on the linked Named Credential. (this took me a long time to figure out and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/329619/77466) was the only thing I could find online about this)

I suspect something similar is going on with the authentication. I have traced the request up until it is sent using `commercepayments.PaymentsHttp.send(request)` & `System.Http.send(request)`. It fails on the former with a 401 unauthorized and succeeds on the latter. I thought about just changing it to use the `System.Http` method but this seemed like a bad idea. I figured they added this for a reason so it should probably be used. (I did try it for shoots and giggles and got an error about callouts not allowed but never went down that rabbit hole since it seemed like a bad idea)

So I guess my question is, does a Payment Gateway require me to use an API that can be authenticated with using the Named Credential? Or does anyone have any additional information/documentation on [CommercePayments.PaymentsHttp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_commercepayments_PaymentsHttp.htm)? I feel like I'm missing something around the relationship between a Payment Gateway and Named Credential when it comes to authentication.

See my comments at the bottom here.

```
String nowFormated = Datetime.now().formatGMT('E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z');
String payload = '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}';

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('/pts/v2/payments/');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('v-c-merchant-id','<cyberSourceMerchantID>');
req.setHeader('Date', nowFormated);
req.setHeader('Host', 'api.cybersource.com');
req.setBody(payload);

String token = CyberSourceHelpers.generateSignatureHeader(
  'POST',
  'api.cybersource.com',
  '/pts/v2/payments/',
  nowFormated,
  '<cyberSourceApiKey>',
  '<cyberSourceApiKeyID>',
  '<cyberSourceMerchantID>',
  payload
);
String digest = 'SHA-256=' + CyberSourceHelpers.generateDigest(payload);
req.setHeader('Digest', digest);
req.setHeader('Signature', token);

// This works
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

// This returns a 401 unauthorized
commercepayments.PaymentsHttp http = new commercepayments.PaymentsHttp();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently this is a known issue when using CyberSource as the Payment Gateway for the B2B LE Checkout Flow. There is a documented workaround that I found in the [B2B Commerce on Lightning Experience](https://partners.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000LovT) group in the Partner Community. See `Other Resources > Cybersource Microform`. Which just links to a public [Quip page: 'Cybersource Custom Credit Card Form'](https://quip.com/nWloALq0WyHO).

FYI the Partner Community group I linked above is private so you would need a login there but the actual Quip docs are public.